# Django: understanding .values() and .values_list() use cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm having trouble understanding under what circumstances are .values() or .values_list() better than just using Model instances?

I think the following are all equivalent:

```
results = SomeModel.objects.all()
for result in results:
    print(result.some_field)

results = SomeModel.objects.all().values()
for result in results:
    print(result['some_field'])

results = SomeModel.objects.all().values_list()
for some_field, another_field in results:
    print(some_field)
```

obviously these are stupid examples, could anyone point out a good reason for using .values() / .values_list() over just using Model instances directly?

edit :

I did some simple profiling, using a noddy model that contained 2 CharField(max_length=100)
Iterating over just 500 instances to copy 'first' to another variable, taking the average of 200 runs I got following results:

```
 Test.objects.all()                                  time: 0.010061947107315063
 Test.objects.all().values('first')                  time: 0.00578328013420105
 Test.objects.all().values_list('first')             time: 0.005257354974746704
 Test.objects.all().values_list('first', flat=True)  time: 0.0052023959159851075
 Test.objects.all().only('first')                    time: 0.011166254281997681
```

So the answer is definitively : performance! (mostly, see knbk answer below)

Comment: when you want list of primary keys you can use SomeModel.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

values() and values_list() are both intended as optimizations for a specific use case: retrieving a subset of data without the overhead of creating a model instance. Good explanation is given in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: So presumably it's more performant than using .only() or .defer() to get the subset of data?  I suppose I could do some profiling to see exactly what kind of difference I'm looking at.

Comment: @Richie Yes. Better to experiment with data and take testing model which can help you to get the applicability of values() and values_list(). You will understand fundamental difference.

Answer (score 7):

`.values()` and `.values_list()` translate to a `GROUP BY` query. This means that rows with duplicate values will be grouped into a single value. So say you have a model `People` the following data:

```
+----+---------+-----+
| id |  name   | age |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 | Alice   |  23 |
|  2 | Bob     |  42 |
|  3 | Bob     |  23 |
|  4 | Charlie |  30 |
+----+---------+-----+
```

Then `People.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)` will return 3 rows: `['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']`. The rows with name `'Bob'` are grouped into a single value. `People.objects.all()` will return 4 rows.

This is especially useful when doing annotations. You can do e.g. `People.objects.values_list('name', Sum('age'))`, and it will return the following results:

```
+---------+---------+
|  name   | age_sum |
+---------+---------+
| Alice   |      23 |
| Bob     |      65 |
| Charlie |      30 |
+---------+---------+
```

As you can see, the ages of both Bob's have been summed, and are returned in a single row. This is different from `distinct()`, which only applies after the annotations.

Performance is just a side-effect, albeit a very useful one.

Comment: I assume it would return 4 rows in the case of People.objects.values() ?
eg.
[{'id':1, 'name':'Alice', 'age':23}, {'id':2, 'name':'Bob', 'age':42}, {'id':3, 'name':'Bob', 'age':23}, {'id':4, 'name':'Charlie', 'age':30}]
And I also assume still 4 rows in the case of People.objects.values('name', 'age')

Comment: Yes, rows are only grouped if all values are the same. If you include both name and age, then the rows `('Bob', 42)` and `('Bob', 23)` are not the same, so it will return 4 rows. If you include the primary key, then the rows are always unique and won't be grouped.

Answer (score 1):

I use **"values_list()"** to create **a Custom Dropdown Single Select Box** for **Django Admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Favourite, Food, Fruit, Vegetable

class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
                                # Here
    FRUITS = Fruit.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
    fruits = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FRUITS)

                                        # Here
    VEGETABLES = Vegetable.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
    vegetables = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VEGETABLES)
    
class FoodInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Food
    form = FoodForm

@admin.register(Favourite)
class FavouriteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FoodInline]
```